# What might cause sporadic small waterspots on ceiling of kitchen?

Tags: hvac, ceiling, waterproofing, water-damage, condensation

I have small (ranging from ~1-5 CM) ,sporadically located, water spots on the ceiling of my kitchen that have progressively gotten worse over the last year.

They seem to be right in the dead center of the ceiling (see image 1).

Above the ceiling is a full bedroom, with a private bathroom. Though directly above where most of the water spots are, is the bed. The toilet/sink/shower is located more directly above the sink.

I have read that this could be due to trapped condensation in the ceiling?

[image: View from front door entry]

[image: Up close view]

[image: Up close view #2]

[image: View from sink]

Comment: Leaking water can travel along strange paths.

Comment: Does that range hood over your gas range vent to the outside? Or does it recirculate filtered air?

Comment: Is that 'W' on your fridge for Wisconsin? Are you located in Wisconsin? Usually I would assume that your supply lines are in that exterior wall. In the frozen north, though, the probability goes up that you've got supply lines running through the ceiling. (The _real_ UW is in Washington.)

Comment: That looks a lot like plain old condensation. If you have high humidity levels (lots of plants, lots of cooking without effective venting, etc) and the upper floor is kept quite cool you can get condensation that would cause stains like you have. Try reducing the humidity by opening a window once in a while and ensure you are venting properly when you cook.